# using Struts Action design question

Tags: java, struts-1

I'm using Struts 1.
I have an Action, and when this Action forwards to a page, I want the page to display properties from a bean.
I'm thinking the Action will make the bean, it needs to populate info from a DB.
Should I have the Action make the bean directly (in the execute()), or use some other class to make the bean, like a factory?

Comment: Do you really have to use Struts-1? Can't use something less than 10 years old like Struts-2 or Stripes?

Comment: we may be going to Struts 2 this year sometime :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends where the data is coming from.  Typically this is a database.  I have always created services to do the data lookups, and invoked the services from the actions.  The services invoked DAOs (data access objects).  The services return objects/beans that are used in the jsps.